# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, netbeans-8

When I try to add columns from the table they give me that error.

```
private void SAVEALLActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{                                        
    model=(DefaultTableModel)tblCont.getModel();
    int col=tblCont.getColumnCount();

    String[]field=new String[col-2];
    String[]value=new String[col-2];
    field[0]="ID";
    field[col-3]="Total";
    int pop=1;
    for (int i = 3; i < col-1; i++) {
    field[pop]=String.valueOf(tblCont.getColumnName(i));
    pop++;
    }


    try {   

        for(int i=0;i<tblCont.getRowCount();i++){
            int opo=1;
          int test=0; int tes=0;
        value[0]=String.valueOf(model.getValueAt(i, 0));    
            for (int j = 3; j < col-1; j++) {

                value[opo]=String.valueOf(model.getValueAt(i, j));
                //Here points my error
                tes =tes + Integer.parseInt(value[pop].trim());
              test=test+tes;
                opo++;
            }

           String tet = Integer.toString(test);
           value[col-4]=tet;
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, tet);
            UpdateRec(field, value, "contribution");
        }


    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());

    }

    TableClearCont();
    ShowContFile();
}
```

Comment: Method names should NOT start with an upper case character. Have you even seen a method from the Java API start with an upper case character? Follow Java conventions!

Comment: Sorry I am still a student but thanks anyway for that reminder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A value in the table is null.

Do some basic debugging. Something like;

```
String cellValue = model.getValueAt(i, j).toString().trim();
//Here points my error
System.out.println(cellValue + " : " + i + " : " + j);
tes += Integer.parseInt(cellValue);
value[opo] = cellValue;
```

Once you know which value is null, fix the data in your table.